# How to activate auto indentation in Powershell ISE in windows?

Tags: powershell

I am using Powershell ISE to write script in windows 7. While writing scripts I have to maintain indentation manually. I didn't find a way to auto indent the script.

Is there any way to perform/enable auto indentation in Powershell ISE or do we need to install any plugin for it?

Comment: You could change Dan Ward's [PrettyPrinter Module](http://www.dtwconsulting.com/PS/Module_PrettyPrinterV1.htm) to edit and replace `$psISE.CurrentFile.Editor.SelectedText` instead of a file on disk

Comment: If you don't mind spending a few bucks, ISESteroids will make you happy: http://www.powertheshell.com/isesteroids/

Answer (score 4):

Vanilla PowerShell ISE doesn't support auto indentation, There are lots of 3rd party ISEs that support it.

Closest you will get in Vanilla PowerShell is the ability to indent multiple lines at once. 
Put the caret where you want to indent Press `Shift + Alt + Arrow Up or Down` and it will create a line vertically across your rows of text. Press `Tab` and it will indent all those lines. This lets you indent whole code blocks and functions.

Comment: Ugh... What kind of IDE skips out on `source => format`?

Comment: The general excuse is that while the ISE has been getting trickles of features every release its not the focus of development and it will eventually be uplifted. There is a very good plugin for visual studio that adds PowerShell support that leverages all of the out of box VS features but I haven't used it. Maybe see if thats better.

Answer (score 3):

[Visual Studio Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/) is probably the best free editor (not only) for powershell scripts. Just open a .ps file with it and you will be suggested to install an appropriate powershell-extension. Then you have auto-format, instellisense, version-control-integration and you can run and debug the scripts from within the editor.

Comment: Doesn't seem to be any PowerShell formatting extension for VS Code. Have you found one?

Answer (score 3):

Auto indentations in PowerShell ISE is not supported but if it's a one time formatting before you wrap up the script you can use an online solution like this one:
http://prettyprinter.de/

You just paste all of the code and click the "Pretty Print" button at the bottom.